# add a custom field to existing tree view Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

I want to add one field call validator to customer invoice (account_invoice).
openerp.py:

```
'depends': ['base','account'],
```

my model:

```
class account_invoice_validator(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    validator = fields.Char()
```

my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

<!-- Model: account.invoice -->
        <record id="view_account_invoice_customer_validator" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="validator"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

the validator column was added to database but i couldn't show it on the tree view (list). What do i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```
<record id="view_account_invoice_customer_validator" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="validator"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: did you upgrade your module? If not upgrade your module and refresh your browser

Comment: oh yes it works. Just realize that rerun in PyCharm doesn't restart actually.

Comment: Remember whenever you modify a xml file you must upgrade your module to see the changes on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<record id="view_account_invoice_customer_validator" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/tree/field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
                <field name="validator"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```